# How to create STC01 Task List

Tags: sap-basis

I've just set up a Fiori demo for a client. To do so I found [the transaction STC01 - Task Lists](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_ssb/helpdata/en/bf/d1b053a647e842e10000000a4450e5/content.htm?loaded_from_frameset=true).

Now I am wondering about some use cases where those kind of task lists would be useful and how to implement client-task lists. I've played around a little bit and saw, that you can add own task lists, steps, etc. but I am not 100% sure how I should do that.

Is there any kind of tutorial, documentation, etc. what is needed to set up a task list? (e. g. documentation about the interfaces, which should be implemented in the classes)

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see the real-life examples of using the tasks list just grab one of the standard task lists provided with the system and check what do they do. For example, you can open `SAP_BASIS_SETUP_INITIAL_CONFIG` list and you'll see that you can automate:

- installation of SAP licenses
- creating RFC-connections
- creating DB-connections
- activating HTTP-services
- installing SSL-certificates
- creating users and assigning roles to them

and so on and so forth.

[image]

It may be useful for replication the tasks list between clients and systems. You can create task list variant in one system and roll-out this variant onto 100 others not to do these monotonous config again.

Read more about configuration in this document:

[Automated Initial Setup of ABAP Systems Based on
SAP NetWeaver](https://help.sap.com/doc/ec180e1ef0e8414896c13522d39f613f/1.0/en-US/Installation__Automated_Initial_SetupE.PDF)